# Condition in WHERE clause of a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp     
    @JOB_TYPE INT = NULL ,
    @MODE INT = 0
AS  
    IF @MODE = 0
    BEGIN        
    SELECT     ProjectId , 
               ProjectName ,               
               D3,
               D2,
               D1,
               F0,
               F1,
               F2,
               F3,                         
    FROM       View_A
    WHERE   (JobTypeId = @JOB_TYPE)                                         
    END

    IF @MODE = 1            --PROJECT WITH NO ACTIVITY IN THE LAST TREE MONTH
    BEGIN        
    SELECT     ProjectId, 
               ProjectName,               
               D3,
               D2,
               D1,
               F0,
               F1,
               F2,
               F3,                         
    FROM       View_A
    WHERE   (JobTypeId = @JOB_TYPE) 
                AND D3 = 0
                AND D2 = 0
                AND D1 = 0
    END
```

As you can see both of the select statement are the same, the only difference is in the `WHERE` clause, that in the second select there are three more conditions.

How can I join the two select statement into one with condition in the WHERE clause ?

Answer (score 4):

I think this will return the same results (I don't really like the mode, but I can't think 100% right now how to remove it)

```
SELECT 
    ProjectId , ProjectName, D3, D2, D1, F0, F1, F2, F3,
FROM 
    View_A 
WHERE 
    (JobTypeId = @JOB_TYPE AND 0 = @Mode)
    OR (1 = @Mode AND JobTypeId = @JOB_TYPE AND D3 = 0 AND D2 = 0 and D1 = 0)
```

Comment: The condition can certainly be simplified to `JobTypeId = @JOB_TYPE AND (@Mode = 0 OR @Mode = 1 AND D3 = 0 AND D2 = 0 and D1 = 0)` (and if `@Mode` can always be only `0` or `1`, `@Mode = 1` can be rid of too), but it will also work as it is.

Answer (score 4):

Check this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp     
@JOB_TYPE INT = NULL ,
@MODE INT = 0
AS  
WITH myCTE
AS
(
    SELECT     ProjectId , 
               ProjectName ,               
               D3,
               D2,
               D1,
               F0,
               F1,
               F2,
               F3                       
    FROM       View_A
    WHERE   (JobTypeId = @JOB_TYPE)                                         
)
Select * from myCTE
where  (@MODE = 0) OR (@MODE = 1 AND D3 = 0 AND D2 = 0 AND D1 = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would be clearer as:

```
where JobTypeId = @Job_Type and -- JobTypeId must always match.
  case -- Filter on the appropriate mode.
    when @Mode = 0 then 1 -- All projects.
    when @Mode = 1 and -- No activity in the last three months.
      D3 = 0 and D2 = 0 and D1 = 0 then 1
    else 0
    end = 1
```

It is easier to add filter modes, though it may not be a good idea to carry this too far.

Answer (score 0):

USE [DATABASE NAME]
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('sp') IS NOT NULL --I THINK WE FIRST NEED TO DROP A PROCEDURE
   DROP PROCEDURE sp

CREATE PROCEDURE sp
    @Job_Type int = null ,@Mode int = 0;
AS
    IF @Mode = 0
    Begin
    SELECT
          Project_Id ,[Project Name] ,D3, D2, D1, F0, F1, F2,F3
    FROM
          View_A
    WHERE
        (JobTypeId = @JOB_TYPE)
    End

```
IF @MODE = 1            --NULL PROJECTS FOR PREVIOUS THREE MONTHS
Begin        
SELECT     
      ProjectId, [Project Name], D3, D2, D1, F0, F1, F2, F3                        
FROM
      View_A
WHERE   
      (JobTypeId = @JOB_TYPE) 
            AND D3 = 0
            AND D2 = 0
            AND D1 = 0
End
```